# some of rows of ms excel sheet date format showing in different format

Tags: excel

How to change format ?
Whenever i open any excel sheet the date format of excel sheet of some of rows shows in different format and even if i try to change the format i couldn't change them.
The highlighted rows format can be changed, but cannot change other rows.
I am using M.S. Office 2013.

***excel sheet original***

[image]

======================================================================

***excel columns which can change***
[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'cannot change'? Do you mean you format the cell in  a particular way using the format menu, but the format is not honoured?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your data came from but obviously your data came in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` but your system is expecting `dd/mm/yyyy`. So the data with 'reasonable' months have been evaluated and formatted as data (what also explains that they are right aligned) and the other ones remained as strings. That are these where a month greater than 12 had been parsed.